# How does load balancing of web applications work - general concept

Tags: apache, nginx, load-balancing

I am struggling to figure out whether I understand load balancing correctly. I have a web app developed in XAMPP. Basically I have a database and the app itself. Afterwards I hosted the app in Digital Ocean in a VPS running Ubuntu where I installed Apache MySQL and PHP. And now I want to understand the requirements for load balancing.

From what I have read so far for load balancing you need at least 3 servers, one of which will be the Apache or NGINX with the respective load balancing module turned on (this server will do the load balancing and just that).

But then I don't really understand how the other 2 servers are supposed to be configured. Do both of them have the same app and database, or does one have the app and the other one the database.

Can someone help me understand the basic concept? I don't need anything going into too much detail.

Thank you.

PS. If i'm planning to deploy the app through Docker in the future does it work the same way? I just have to have a container for the server and other 2 or more containers for the app and the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need minimum 4 servers: one load balancer, two app servers, one database. NGINX/Apache would load balance between the two app servers.